# How to API rate limit server calls in rxjava and retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I would like to be able to limit my calls to the server to say 20 times per second. Else the server will blacklist my IP.

How can I accomplish this with rxjava and retrofit? Is there a simple function?

Otherwise how could I tell an observer on subscription to wait n seconds before making the server call?

Comment: What should happen when you make, say, 30 calls? Cancel the remaining calls or delay them?

Comment: delay! Basically i have a bunch of views and each of them can independantly request updates from the server at the same time, if your on a tablet for example, and there are multiple views, this will kill the api limit. If i could just basically sleep those threads so i dont make more than 20 calls per second.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Timer Operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) to delay it.

Here is an example:

```
Observable.timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .map(aLong -> null) // this will be called after 500 milli seconds
                .subscribe();
```

TimeUnit can be anything from microseconds to days, so it is very handy. There are other operators also like [Delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html)

Example:

```
Observable.empty()
                .delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .flatMap(new Function<Object, ObservableSource<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<?> apply(Object o) throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: I've had a look at these function but from the docs it seems like they delay the response. So they make the call to the server. then wait to show the repsonse? in this case i would have exceeded the api limit. I need to limit the request to the server? Is that what these functions infact do? delay the request and not the response?

Comment: in the above example, it will delay whatever comes next after timer. i.e map or flatMap so you can implement your logic in that way. you can use flatMap to return your desired observable.

Comment: im struggeling to get my desired observable . once i add in timer it makes the return value in subscribe() into a long. I'd like to keep it as CustomObject?

Comment: you can use flatMap to return whatever observable you want and then you can user map to perform any action on it. you can make a chain like timer > flatMap > map > subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

If you were on 2.x, there is a `spanout` operator that can do this. For 1.x, you can do a `flatMap` of a timer and maxConcurrency = 1:

```
Observable<Observable<Result>> tasks = ...

tasks.flatMap(o ->
    Observable.timer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .flatMap(u -> o)
, 1)
.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: When i try these methods in .subscribe() i no longer recieve CustomObjects its now a long? obviously from the timer. How to i add a timer but keep my CustomObject as the return value?

Comment: That code is an individually realized stream, thus it will call the service as fast as you call the outer method of it. You need something more overarching than one sequence. What is triggering that method btw?

Comment: That method is called on bindview in a recycler view. So i have a list of items in a recycler view and on bindview i want it to load the chart. (I have already taken care of caching to REALM, but lets assume its not in REALM yet it needs to download the chart on bind view. So now you see why im smashing my api limit. If theres 20 views visible in the recycler view there is at least 20 requests to the api at the same time. I need to space them out :/